# Windows 7: can't reopen minimised window on taskbar, preview doesWork

Tags: windows

I have a program and want to either bring its Window to the front or reopen it after it is minimised.

It is on the taskbar and hovering over it shows the preview of the window. However clicking on it does not make it reopen and become visible.

This happens with every single program in Windows.

Any advice on how to force the Window to reopen?

The issue is NOT that the window is on another screen. That solution does not work!!!!!!

(I couldn't figure out if you can request a thread be reopened, because this is the same error as described here, but the answers were not correct! Windows 7: can't reopen minimised window on taskbar, preview OK)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing this can be, is that the window is open outside of the screen (as if it is on another screen).

The best way to get this to work is first be sure the window is open. Hover the window in the taskbar so you see the preview, then on the preview, rightclick and hit `restore` if its still in minimized state.

Now again hover the window so it shows the preview and rightclick it so the popup appears again. This time click `Move`.

Now press any cursor key (for example <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and move your mouse.

The window will now be snapped to your mousecursor. and when you left click, it will release the window.

If the window keeps disappearing, you can save its current location by holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while clicking on the close button.

Comment: "The only thing this can be, is that the window is open outside of the screen (as if it is on another screen)."

This is not the solution!!!  The preview window has the target window in the correct place, when you minimize the window in front of the window you are trying to bring to the foreground, it is in the correct place!  The problem is that clicking on the icon in the taskbar is not bringing the window to the forefront!

Comment: Have you actually tried the solution before telling us that it doesn't work?

Comment: Well, you see, the thing is, I suspect something keeps minimising all apps. Something that would immediately be noticed if you make the app visible in the way I suggest, because it will stick to your mouse until you click and as soon as you click the window would vanish. But that would only become obvious if you tried this. There just is no other thing that can hide a window like you describe.

Comment: Deleting my prev comment; only muddles an already messy Q&A

Comment: @panhandel gotcha. removed my response to it. :)